# iPad ID reset after homesharing

Tags: ipad, home-sharing

I homeshared my iPad to my husband's computer via homesharing and all went well. But it reset the Apple ID on my iPad to my husband's email address. Now I can't access iStore with my own ID.

I checked that my ID and password was still stored under general in the iPad but this has not fixed the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to go into Settings -> Store, log out of the account, and log into the account that you want to use to access the store. That should not affect your home sharing setup, and will allow you to use your account for the store.